# u-boot and scripting engine

Tags: shell, u-boot

Does anybody heard of or has an idea about possibility of integration some scripting engine (like tcl, perl, python etc.) into U-boot?
The reason is that U-boot is major tool used during board bring-up and it's programming possibilities are quite limited and more abilities are wanted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is usually handled off-device.  Historically the most common way to do this was with expect and more recently in mainline U-Boot we now have test/py/test.py that works with both sandbox and real hardware.